# Авторизация на сайте без костылей

Tags: python, python-3.x, авторизация, requests, instagram

Всем привет!
Вопрос: есть сайт, допустим

```
https://instagram.com
```

чтобы пройти авторизацию на нем через web нужно зайти на главную страницу, спарсить один кук, зайти еще куда то, спарсить второй кук, потом все это отдать на post-запросе, вставив в headers спарсенные куки.

*Такая конструкция не надежная, ломается при малейшем изменении процедуры авторизации. И меня не покидает ощущение, что это дичайший костыль и все можно сделать гораздо проще и лаконичнее, без парсеров.*

Так ли это? Есть ли варианты, на примере авторизации в https://instagram.com ? Не обязательно через requests, на выходе меня интересуют только куки.

Comment: Не надо парсить отдельные куки, просто берите и храните вообще все куки, что даёт сайт, да и всё. Ведь так же браузеры и делают

Comment: @andreymal можно пример, как это сделать? или ссылку на документацию

Comment: с requests.Session не получилось

Comment: как я понимаю ввиду того, что некоторые куки берутся с главной страницы, некоторые вообще из js. просто послать session post не пройдет. есть варианты воспроизвести все переходы в браузере, сохранив все куки, но не запуская браузер, а используя какуню нибудь библиотеку?